# How can I delay/queue all disk activity on a certain directory/disk until a certain point?

Tags: linux-kernel, io, delay

I would like to be able to issue a command in a script that would stop disk activity to a certain directory (or disk) and queue it until I issue another command that would 'resume' the disk and all disk activity happening while the disk was stopped can happen once I've issued the 2nd command.

You could think of it similar when a mechanical drive is 'sleeping' and when disk activity is happening on that disk it will take less than a few seconds to turn on again before any activity can happen, so the program will just hang while it's waiting for disk activity to finish. I want to be able to control when this 'sleeping' mechanism of queuing activity for later starts and stops (I am not talking about extending the spin up time of a disk or something like that, I just used it as an example).

Comment: Apparently, using the `fsfreeze` command - although I've never heard of it before ... read [this](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/48653/does-quiesce-exist-for-linux) - it's called [Quiescing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quiesce).